# How do I prove that a bit by bit PKE scheme (that is IND-CPA secure) for an n-bit message is not IND-CCA-2 secure?

Tags: public-key, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Gen generates Pk and Sk (l bits each), Enc encrypts m (length l) but by bit using each bit of Pk respectively, Dec decrypts ciphertext bit by bit using each bit of Sk respectively. How do I prove this scheme is not IND-CCA-2 secure?

Comment: ... You find a CCA attack against the scheme, and show that the attack works. ​ ​